# Hardware PWM on Raspberry Pi 2 using .NET Core 3.1

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I would like to use hardware PWM on a GPIO port to generate RC-5 IR codes with an IR LED.

I read that .NET Core now has [PWM support](https://github.com/dotnet/iot/blob/master/src/System.Device.Gpio/System/Device/Pwm/PwmChannel.Linux.cs) and that the Pi has at least one PWM-enabled GPIO pin, but I can find precious little documentation on how to access it. The `PwmChannel.Create()` method requires a chip number, and passing 0 doesn't work.

I'm hoping that the hardware can provide the 36 kHz carrier signal, and the `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` method should give me sufficient resolution to generate the RC-5 output over it... but I just can't get `PwmChannel` working.

I would be very glad of any pointers on how to do this... or am I on the wrong track altogether?

Comment: I read that:  ".NET Core 3.1 is supported on the following operating systems: Debian: 9+, ...". Does it mean Raspbian 10 buster is also OK?

Comment: I found Daren May's .NET 3.0 tutorial good. Do you have any other tutorials as good for newbies? - ".NET Core and GPIO on Rpi - Daren May 2019oct16"
https://darenmay.com/blog/net-core-and-gpio-on-the-raspberry-pi---leds-and-gpio/.

Comment: I would check that you can generate on off signals accurately at the sub-millisecond rate before you bother adding the carrier.  If you check the resulting timings you may find that it can't be done with .NET on the Pi.

Comment: @tlfong01 Apparently so! I installed the latest Raspbian distro and the latest .NET Core runtime successfully. (I have RS232 communication working nicely. It's just the PWM that's proving tricky.)

Comment: @Olly How did you get RS232 working on a Pi? Special hardware?

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, it's a thing called Serial Hat. This, or something similar: https://www.pishop.us/product/serial-hat-rs232/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having the same issue, I found the solution. You have to enable PWM in the boot config file.

Add this line to your `/boot/config.txt` file:

```
dtoverlay=pwm-2chan,pin=12,pin2=13,func=4,func2=4
```

Answer found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/iot/issues/1123).

Answer (score 1):

For me it works without any edits to /boot/config.txt, using .net5, the NuGet package System.Device.Gpio from Microsoft and the standard Raspberry OS. A hardware-PWM-GPIO or a software-PWM-GPIO can both be called with SoftwarePwmChannel:

```
System.Device.Pwm.Drivers.SoftwarePwmChannel buzzerPwm = new System.Device.Pwm.Drivers.SoftwarePwmChannel(16, 400, 0.5, false, controller, false);
```

-or (hardware PWM)-

```
System.Device.Pwm.PwmChannel buzzerPwm = new System.Device.Pwm.Drivers.SoftwarePwmChannel(12, 400, 0.5, false, controller, false);
```

and then use it with for instance:

```
buzzer = new Iot.Device.Buzzer.Buzzer(buzzerPwm);
```