# How can I control a Cambridge Audio CXA81 amplifier using its "IR IN" input?

Tags: pi-2

I would like to control the volume on my CXA81 from a Raspberry Pi.

I already use a Serial HAT to send control codes to the amplifier. However, unfortunately, the volume may only be controlled using IR—either through the conventional IR sensor on the front, or a 3.5 mm mono input on the rear that is described this way in the manual:

> 4. IR IN
>
> Allows modulated IR commands from an IR repeater or custom install systems to be received by the amplifier.

1. Can I use the audio output to generate the IR signal?
2. If not, is there some kind of USB to wired IR adapter I could use?
3. If not, could I use PWM, or something else, to generate the "modulated IR" output needed?

What hardware and cables would I need?

The programming/software side is not *too* scary, but I'm an electronics NOOB. Anything that avoids reaching for the soldering iron would be welcome, especially since i'm hoping this will be moderately presentable!

I previously came at this from a different angle (see [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/hardware-pwm-on-raspberry-pi-2-using-net-core-3-1)). I never got that working, but I'd much rather use the wired IR input than the optical one; hence this new post.